# Making the query shorter and optimize

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have lots of key word that I need to filter.  Is there any way to make the query below shorter?

I need to find fields that contains key key words below.  I can use any different way as long as I can do the same thing.  I expect to have more key words as time goes.

```
IIf([2CP].[commodity description] Like ('*SCRAP*') 
Or [2CP].[commodity description] Like ('*PART*') 
Or [2CP].[commodity description] Like ('*MIL*') 
Or [2CP].[commodity description] Like ('*Material*') 
Or [2CP].[commodity description] Like ('*PTS*') 
Or [2CP].[commodity description] Like ('*SDDC*') 
Or [2CP].[commodity description] Like ('*SEAT*') 
Or [2CP].[commodity description] Like ('*FOOD*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*SCRAP*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*PART*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*MIL*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*Material*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*PTS*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*SDDC*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*SEAT*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*FOOD*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*lorries motorcycles bicycles Foods*') 
Or [2CP].[raw_cmd_desc] Like ('*lorries*') 
Or [2CP].[shipper name] Like ('*SCRAP*') 
Or [2CP].[shipper name] Like ('*PART*') 
Or [2CP].[shipper name] Like ('*MIL*') 
Or [2CP].[shipper name] Like ('*SDDC*')
Or [2CP].[shipper name] Like ('*FOOD*')
Or [2CP].[shipper name] Like ('*Hoegh*')
Or [2CP].[shipper name] Like ('*NYK*')
,1,0)
```

Comment: Start with storing a list of keywords in a separate table. Then do a join ON

Comment: @GregViers Join will have to match exactly.  I need a way to search columns that contains above key words.  Is there join function that I do not know?

Comment: JOIN does not have to match exactly. when writing your on just use LIKE '%' + keywordtable.keyword + '%' instead of =

Answer (score 0):

Consider a VBA user-defined function that receives field values as parameters and loops through a table list of all keywords (without asterisks). The beauty too is if at least one *True* exists, method exits the loop and function and does not need to check all other values.

**VBA** function *(save in a standard module)*

```vb
Public Function FindString(commodityParam As String, raw_cmdParam As String, shipperParam As String) As Boolean

    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim tmp As Boolean

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT keyword FROM KeyWordsTable")

    Do While Not rst.EOF            
        If commodityParam Like "*" & rst!keyword & "*" _
            Or raw_cmdParam Like "*" & rst!keyword & "*" _
            Or shipperParam Like "*" & rst!keyword & "*" Then

            tmp = True
            GoTo ExitFunction
        End If

        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

ExitFunction:
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    TestLoop = tmp

End Function
```

**SQL** *(VBA function can be used in any SQL query)*

```
-- SELECT WITH CALCULATED COLUMN
SELECT *, FindString([commodity description], [raw_cmd_desc], [shipper name]) As Output
FROM [2CP];

-- SELECT WITH WHERE CONDITION
SELECT * FROM [2CP]
WHERE FindString([commodity description], [raw_cmd_desc], [shipper name]) = True;

-- APPEND QUERY
INSERT INTO (ID, BooleanValue)
SELECT ID, FindString([commodity description], [raw_cmd_desc], [shipper name])
FROM [2CP];

-- UPDATE QUERY
UPDATE [2CP]
SET BooleanValue = FindString([commodity description], [raw_cmd_desc], [shipper name]);

-- DELETE QUERY
DELETE FROM [2CP]
WHERE FindString([commodity description], [raw_cmd_desc], [shipper name]) = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  All data is not being filtered at all.  I get result as none of the key words meet the criteria.  Please let me know, if you can help further.

Comment: Before posting this, I tested this approach. This method worked for my example data. Did you build a *keywordsTable*? Please post sample data and **full** query not just the calculated column to see where filtering is run as I see no `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: I created the table with "keyword" as a field name.  I tried to use one of your queries below.  I tried to use on simpler table where the table has FORD 2016 and I set key word as FORD, but i will not find it. 
 Please let me know, if I should check something else.  SELECT * FROM [2CP]
WHERE FindString([commodity description], [raw_cmd_desc], [shipper name]) = True;

Comment: Hmmm...not sure what the issue. I re-checked on my end. Is your test *FORD 2016* in one of the three columns passed into function? Any errors popping up? Did you change VBA function in any way from above?

Comment: I did not change any of the VBA function.  One of the columns have the data.  It looks like it should work.  I will double check all the spellings.